# Ef 4.x dbcontext generator fails when executed

Tags: entity-framework, t4

I have vs2010, installed Entity framework 4.3.1 from nuget, installed the EF 4.x DbContext Generator from microsoft. I create a project then try to add a new EF 4.x DbContext Generator item but the following error. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

> Error 1   Running transformation:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Unable to locate file    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.TextTemplatingService.ResolvePath(String
>   path)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.TextTemplatingService.ResolvePath(String
>   path)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig,
>   MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method,
>   Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes
>   methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingE78BCB29E8D7A2F9432A449161229C3F.GeneratedTextTransformation.DynamicHost.ResolvePath(String
>   path)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingE78BCB29E8D7A2F9432A449161229C3F.GeneratedTextTransformation.MetadataLoader.TryCreateEdmItemCollection(String
>   sourcePath, String[] referenceSchemas, EdmItemCollection&
>   edmItemCollection)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingE78BCB29E8D7A2F9432A449161229C3F.GeneratedTextTransformation.MetadataLoader.CreateEdmItemCollection(String
>   sourcePath, String[] referenceSchemas)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingE78BCB29E8D7A2F9432A449161229C3F.GeneratedTextTransformation.MetadataLoader.TryLoadAllMetadata(String
>   inputFile, MetadataWorkspace& metadataWorkspace)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingE78BCB29E8D7A2F9432A449161229C3F.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.RunTransformation(TemplateProcessingSession
>   session, String source, ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, String&
>   result)       1   1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly its a case of PEBKAC. I hadn't created my edmx file. Once I had done this all I needed to do was right click on the model. Select "Add Code Generation item".

Comment: I'm just starting to work with EF and C#. This post helped me figure out where I stepped of the path!